# Read both multi-part form data and json input from WCF-RESTful service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, multipartform-data

I want to create a WCF-RESTful web service method,in which i need to upload an image(multipart-form data) along with some other information (in JSON format).
This web service will be accessed by android and iPhone application to send Image and json information as

```
{ "description":"blah blah", "id"=123,"Comments":"blah blah" }
```

at the same request.
My service input will be Stream,I want to read both image and the above json content from the stream itself.

```
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
            jsonData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > 0);
```

How can i read the Passed JSON string from the Stream?

Comment: For REST, leave to WCF, Web API is much simpler

Comment: what i want here is that, i am passing an image(as attachment) as multipart-form data also a json data as in question.Here in web service i want to get both JSON data and image which passed from client application(using multi part form data ) as well.how can i get it done from webservice, please help me with code or link to any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). Or if you want more control over serialization [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Yeah, I am using JSON.net for serialization/deserialization.                  But what i want here is that, i am passing an image(as attachment) as multipart-form data also a json data as in question.Here in web service i want to get both JSON data and image which passed from client application(using multi part form data ) as well.how can i get it done from webservice, please help me with code or link to any solution.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734941/upload-file-from-html-form-multipart-form-data-to-wcf-rest-service-as-a-stream