# How to save the stream from AFNetwork by C#

Tags: c#, ios

I use the AFNETWORKing write a iOS client to send the *.jpeg from iOS device. Now,I can receive the stream from the ios. If I save this stream to a jpeg file, it cannot be opened. I use the notepad++ open it and find this not all the stream is jpeg data.

its header likes this:

```
--Boundary+3064FAAD3A74E02F
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
----others code
```

how can I save this stream?

Answer (score 0):

I sold it myself.Now I know the problem which I meet. I need to encode the stream and split it find the key work I need. I am sure that the afnetwork has sent the content-type,filename into the stream. I find this poster:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734941/upload-file-from-html-form-multipart-form-data-to-wcf-rest-service-as-a-stream)

if you want to see more problem like this,Google the key word: multipart/form-data and wcf